# Adding a label name to select pull down

Tags: php

Trying to add a label to a dynamically populated pull down.

```
        for ($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++) {
        $data['months'][] = array(
            'text' .=> 'Month',
            'text'  => 'strftime('%B', mktime(0, 0, 0, $i, 1, 2000)),
            'value' => ' ', sprintf('%02d', $i)
        );
    }
```

is not working.
Basically, I want the initial select options to be blank; so when a user comes by and forgets to select it, the proper error shows.

The code above (without my example, `'text' .=> 'Month',` (which produces an error) generates a pulldown that has the 12 months.  I am trying to add the field label (Month) above January.

Comment: Explain what youre doing and whats wrong properly

Comment: How do you use later the array `$data`?

Comment: We need a little more context here. Obviously this code alone doesn't magically produce a `<select>` list. Show what happens to this array

Comment: `.=>` looks like a syntax error.

Comment: I've edited my post with additional detail, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the initial option to be blank there are two ways to achieve it :

**#1 : use JavaScript.** Example (copy-paste next code in a HTML file and open it in your browser) :

```
<select id="months">   ◄■■ SELECT ID IS "MONTHS".
  <option value="1">January</option>
  <option value="2">February</option>
  <option value="3">March</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("months").selectedIndex = -1; ◄■■ NO OPTION SELECTED FOR "MONTHS".
</script>
```

**#2 : add a blank option before you fill the array :**

```
$data['months'][] = array(    ◄■■ ADD THE BLANK ITEM FIRST.
    'text'  => '',
    'value' => '-1'
);
for ($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++) {
     $data['months'][] = array(
         'text'  => strftime('%B', mktime(0, 0, 0, $i, 1, 2000)),
         'value' => sprintf('%02d', $i)
     );
 }
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for the explanation!! Totally see what I was doing wrong - got it working. :)